# Recargar un div que contenga una sentencia IF y ELSE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo la siguiente duda al recargar un `div` donde tengo una sentencia `if` y `else` que dependiendo el valor obtenido por una consulta me debería cambiar entre un gráfico o una tabla, pero lo quiero mostrar sin recargar toda la página.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <?php
        require_once __DIR__ . 'controller.php';
        $auth=new System();
        $sql2=$auth->runQuery("SELECT status FROM Productos Where idProducto = '1' ");
        $sql2->execute();
        $sqlRow2=$sql2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>


    <div id="datos">

        <?php
            if($sqlRow2['status'] == 2)
                {
                    echo "<div> Aquí mostraré un Charjs </div>";
                }
            else
                {
                    echo "<span> se mostrará una tabla </span>";
                }
        ?>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function actualizardatos(){
                value = $('#datos').text();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "consulta.php",
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#datos').text(data);
                    }
                });
            };
            setInterval(actualizardatos, 100);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es mi archivo `consulta.php`:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . 'controller.php';
    $auth = new System();
    
    $sql=$auth->runQuery("SELECT status FROM Productos Where idProducto = '1' ");
    $sql->execute();
    $sqlRow=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    echo $sqlRow['status'];

?>
```

De esta consulta obtengo un valor 1 o 2 que se ve reflejado en la etiqueta `< div id="datos" ></ div >` hasta ahí todo bien, pero el gráfico o la tabla dentro de las sentencias `if` o `else` no se muestra.

Por favor me pueden ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- Todo el proceso lo tendrías que realizar cuando obtienes la respuesta de tu servidor:

```
success: function(data){
   $('#datos').text(data);
}
```

2.- Quedando tu peticion de la siguiente manera:

```
success: function(data){
   if(data == '2')
       {
        $("#datos").html("<div> Aquí mostraré un Charjs </div>");
       }

   else
       {
         $("#datos").html("<span> se mostrará una tabla </span>");
       }
}
```

3.- Estarias agregando al elemento que tiene el **ID datos** el contenido que esta dentro de `.html`

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo apliqué a mi código. La única duda que tengo es, si o si todo el código html irá en `$("#datos").html` pero si quisiera utilizar `php` no me dejaría en ese caso que me recomiendas que podría hacer.

Comment: Recuerda, solo estás modificando el **HTML interno** del elemento con ID datos, lo que yo veo que estás haciendo, es cargar de primero, los datos con PHP y con Ajax ejecutas una función cada 100 milisegundos no ?? Y esto mostrara información de acuerdo a lo que traiga tu consulta. Esto daría lugar a otra pregunta, con el código que haz logrado te recomiendo fórmular otra pregunta con las dudas que te surgieron. Con gusto te responderé. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, entonces formularé otro pregunta.